# Reducing log noise for http requests, contextmanager or custom logging level?

Tags: python-3.x, logging, contextmanager

I have a logger that I use for most of my programs that I set at `logging.INFO`.  This to me seems the most reasonable setting as the stuff I log isn't necessarily a warning, etc...   Problem is, `requests` and `urllib` use `logging.INFO` for each one of their HTTP requests.  This creates super long logs for some of my ETL processes, and it's not necessarily helpful in any way.

I was thinking about two solutions, the first being to create a context managing function that sets the script's overall level to `logging.WARNING` just during the ETL portion where there is no useful logging info.  The other option is to create a custom logging level in-between `logging.INFO` and `logging.WARNING`.  Which would be more re-usable and work more efficiently for the purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I configure my logger, I always add `logging.getLogger('requests').propagate = False` to avoid *contaminating* my logs with logging from the Requests library.

For example:

```
def init_logger(config_file=None, log_level=logging.INFO):
    # Configure the logging system
    if config_file:
        logging.config.fileConfig(config_file, disable_existing_loggers=False)
    else:
        logging.basicConfig(level=log_level)

    # Avoid output from the requests module
    logging.getLogger('requests').propagate = False


def main():
    init_logger(…)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```